# Python decorating class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to decorate a `class` with arguments but cannot get it to work:

This is the decorator:

```
 def message(param1, param2):
   def get_message(func):
        func.__init__(param1,param2)

   return get_message
```

class where I want to put the decorator

```
@message(param1="testing1", param2="testing2")
class SampleClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
     pass
```

But this is not working , I am getting an error when running this.  Does anyone know what the problem ?, I am trying to create a decorator to initialise classes with some values.

Comment: Where does the decorator return the object to bind to `SampleClass`?

Comment: Yeah that's what I needed help with. I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: Did you try returning something from `get_message()`?

Comment: `func.__init__(param1,param2)` this cannot happen cause you have only  `__init__(self)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm having trouble figuring out what you're trying to do. If you want to decorate a class with a decorator that takes arguments, one way to do it is like this.

2020-09-03:

Thank you Maria-Ines Carrera for pointing out that the original code doesn't actually handle classes inheriting from other classes correctly and user2357112 supports Monica for proposing a solution that does work.

```
# function returning a decorator, takes arguments
def message(param1, param2):
    # this does the actual heavy lifting of decorating the class
    # it takes the original class, modifies it in place, and returns
    # the same class
    def wrapper(wrapped):
        the_init = wrapped.__init__

        def new_init(self):
            self.param1 = param1
            self.param2 = param2
            the_init(self)

        def get_message(self):
            return "message %s %s" % (self.param1, self.param2)

        wrapped.__init__ = new_init
        wrapped.get_message = get_message

        return wrapped
    return wrapper


class Pizza(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Pizza initialization"


@message("param1", "param2")
class Pizza2(Pizza):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Pizza2 initialization"
        super(Pizza2, self).__init__()

pizza_with_message = Pizza2()

# prints "message param1 param2"
print pizza_with_message.get_message()
```

This prints the following:

```
Pizza2 initialization
Pizza initialization
message param1 param2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I wanted to do!

Comment: I don't think this works -- it results in infinite recursion when trying to instantiate the decorated class. That's because `__init__` calls its super() (wrapped), which re-decorates itself, which calls `__init__` again, etc.


I'm not sure there is a way to do this in python 2 :(

Comment: @Maria-InesCarrera    Thank you for pointing this out. I figured out how to reproduce the error you described and have fixed the answer. I needed to change the first argument to `super` so it skips the outermost level of wrapper class.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet: But now you're skipping the wrapped class's `__init__` method. Plus, any non-`__init__` methods that use 2-argument `super` in the wrapped class still hit infinite recursion. Creating a subclass just isn't a good way to go for this - modifying the original class in-place works better.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks for the suggestion. I created some new functions off to the side and then stapled them into the class. It seems to work.