# Is there any way to mark classes in Python?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a bunch of classes in a Python module. I want some way to mark these classes, maybe with something like a decorator so that I can get access to only these classes from my module. For example:

```
class One:
    ...

@marked
class Two:
    ...

@marked
class Three:
    ...
```

What I actually want to do is get these marked classes in a list somehow, dynamically, in run time. Something like this:

```
marked_classes = [Two, Three]
```

What would be the ideal way to do this in Python? Thanks. Note: It does not have to be a decorator. I just added that part to explain the question.

Edit: Something important to keep in mind is that you don't have to know the class names to actually get a list of the marked classes. So something like `marked_classes.append(Two)` is obviously not going to work.

Comment: `marked_classes.append(Foo)`? You could wrap that in a decorator if you'd like...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please check the edits.

Comment: Um, how do you plan to use the decorator if you don't have the name? That doesn't make any sense. If you can do `@marked class Foo` then you can do `marked_classes.append(Foo)`

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "access to *only* these classes"; if you can import the module, you can access any name at the global scope. Do you just want an easily accessible *grouping* of some subset of the classes?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class decorator that has a list inside it. In the decorator, you can take the class and add it to the list.

Once the module loading is done, you should have the classes in the list.

Some help:

https://www.codementor.io/sheena/advanced-use-python-decorators-class-function-du107nxsv

[Python decorating class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924848/python-decorating-class/40924956)

Comment: Could you maybe expand the answer with some code example?

Comment: Any reason why not simply `marked_classes.append(Foo)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Separation of responsibility: it's not the the markers responsibility to know about which classes have to be in the list. Ideally whoever wants their classes to be "marked", would just import the decorator and apply it to the class

Comment: ... same with the list?

Comment: A mutable list being imported and modified by anyone who wants it?

Comment: Yes. That is the *exact same effect as your decorator*. If I can import `marked_classes` I can import `marked`.

Comment: So, if you wanted to maintain a constant interface and change the underlying container, you could use a decorator. You could also just use a custom class, `Marker().mark(Foo)`. But mostly, I'm trying to get the OP to actually describe why they think they *need* a decorator, and *specifically why* they can't just use a `list`. They have stated "Something important to keep in mind is that you don't have to know the class names to actually get a list of the marked classes. So something like marked_classes.append(Two) is obviously not going to work." but that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

The decorator is fairly simple to write.

```
marked_classes = []


def mark(cls):
    marked_classes.append(cls)
    return cls


class One:
    ...


@marked
class Two:
    ...


@marked
class Three:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put your classes inside a module inside a package

```
/package
    __init__.py
    module.py
```

then in your **init**.py file assign the classes you want 'public' to the **all** variable list

`__init__.py:`

```
from .module import Two, Three
__all__ = [Two, Three]
```

Then when calling it:

`script.py`

```
from package import *
# or
from package import Two, Three
```

Comment: saw your edit, maybe I did not understand your question